# Sorting Collections within and by the Sum of Another Collections

Tags: c#, sorting, collections

2 classes

```
   public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public List<Fee> Fees {get;set;}
    }

    public class Fee
    {
        public int FeeID { get; set;}
        public decimal FeeAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

let say there are 10 students objects Student[] stud = new Student[10]

if stud[0] has 2 fees ( Fee[2] ) and they are

```
FeeID=1, FeeAmount=54.23
FeeID=2, FeeAmount=234.98
```

if stud[1] has 1 fees ( Fee[2] ) and they are

```
FeeID=1, FeeAmount=9.99
```

if stud[2] has 3 fees ( Fee[3] ) and they are

```
FeeID=1, FeeAmount=123.45
FeeID=2, FeeAmount=67.89
FeeID=3, FeeAmount=987.65
```

I need to sort the Student Collections by TotalAmount(Fee Collection)

```
TotalAmount of Fee 
stud[0] = 54.23+234.98=289.21
stud[1] = =9,99
stud[2] = 123.45+67.89+987.65=1178.99
```

there for after sorted it should become

```
stud[0] = 123.45+67.89+987.65=1178.99
stud[1] = 54.23+234.98=289.21
stud[2] = =9,99
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
stud = stud.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fees.Sum(fee => fee.FeeAmount)).ToArray();
```

Gotta love LINQ :)

A couple of things to note:

- This will still only calculate the sum of the fees once per student
- This will *not* currently handle null elements. Do you need to? (You seem to have a fixed array size... perhaps use `List<Student>` instead?)
- Unless you actually *need* it as an array afterwards, just drop the `ToArray` call. Be aware that it *will* sort it every time you iterate through it unless you use `ToArray` or `ToList` though.

Comment: `Fees` is `List<Fee>`, so you have to specify how the `Sum` will be performed (specify a property within `Fee`).

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = stud.OrderByDescending(s => s.Fees.Sum(f => f.FeeAmount)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Linq query should do the job:

```
stud =
    (from s in stud
     orderby s.Fees.Sum(f => f.FeeAmount)
     select s)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var students = new List<Student>() { .. add students here ... };
students.OrderBy(x => x.Fees.Sum(y => y.FeeAmount));
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you use an old .net framework (without Linq) :

```
public class Student : IComparable
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Fee> Fees { get; set; }

    private decimal TotalAmount
    {
        get
        {
            decimal total = 0;
            if (Fees != null)
                foreach (var fee in Fees)
                    total += fee.FeeAmount;
            return total;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        //Ascending
        //return TotalAmount.CompareTo((obj as Student).TotalAmount);

        //Descending
        return (obj as Student).TotalAmount.CompareTo(TotalAmount);
    }
}

public class Fee
{
    public int FeeID { get; set; }
    public decimal FeeAmount { get; set; }
}


List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
...
students.Sort();
```

Linq is better...